# How to get chain information from database?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table named "referral" and it contains two columns named "refer_by" and "refer_to". "refer_by" column stores the id of the user, who refer someone, and "refer_to" store the id of the user, who was referred by "refer_by" user.

Following is the stored info.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 8 | 9 |
| 9 | 10 |
| 15 | 16 |
| 18 | 20 |

I want to get all the referral list where refer_by=1. For Example refer_by=1 refer 2 and 5, 2 refer 6, 5 refer7 and so on.

I am using following query but it is failing with reason "ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: recursive reference to query "referral" must not appear within its non-recursive term".

```
@Query(value = "WITH RECURSIVE referral AS " +
            "( " +
                "SELECT ref1.* FROM referral ref1 WHERE ref1.refer_by =:referByUserId " +
                    "UNION ALL " +
                "SELECT ref2.* FROM referral ref2 " +
                    "INNER JOIN " +
                "referral ref3 ON ref2.refer_by = ref3.refer_to " +
            ") " +
            "SELECT reff.refer_by, reff.refer_to FROM referral reff", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object[]> testt(final Long referByUserId);
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: `FROM` of both part of union should be your table, not cte.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your recursive CTE has the same name as your table (`referral`) - and the database cannot resolve the ambiguity.

I would recommend using a different alias to the CTE, as in:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM referral WHERE refer_by =:referByUserId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.* 
    FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN referral r ON r.refer_by = c.refer_to
)
SELECT refer_by, refer_to FROM cte
```